# How many $8$-digit telephone numbers contain no zero if the first digit is not permitted to be $0$ or $1$? at least one zero?

Tags: combinatorics

The telephone numbers in a certain area consist of $8$ digits. The first digit of a telephone number is not permitted to be $0$ or $1$.

a. How many of the telephone numbers do not contain any zeros?

- I'm stuck because I use the $8$ digits times $9$ since it say do not contain zero, but it shows my answer is wrong.

b. How many of the telephone numbers contain at least one zero?

- have no idea where to start

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: Hint for $a)$ You have $8$ choices for the first digits and $9$ for every other digit.  (the result is $8\cdot 9^7$) To get $b)$, calculate the number of possible numbers. This time, you have $8$ choices for the first digit and $10$ for every other digit. Do you see how this and $a)$ gives $b)$ ?